# How is Object.Equals() implemented "in the end"?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Out of curiosity I wanted to see how the `Object.Equals()` method is implemented.

So I've browsed the [source code of Object](https://source.dot.net/?msclkid=0734d64fc61211ec9bb5f8db5d88c63c#System.Private.CoreLib/Object.cs,517682d5f6f4f8b4,references) which finally led me to [RuntimeHelpers.Equals()](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/RuntimeHelpers.CoreCLR.cs,9d03beb7e780f5e9,references). But the Equals method of RuntimeHelpers is implemented externally without a Dllimport attribute.

Where can I find the "extern" implementation of `RuntimeHelpers.Equals()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find that implemented in the runtime itself. A good entry point when looking for the implementations of these extern methods is [ecalllist.h](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/eb9dd67ce9fc64c468cf5c795fda7057310c22fc/src/coreclr/vm/ecalllist.h). Here we find:

```cpp
FCFuncElement("Equals", ObjectNative::Equals)
```

So it's implemented by `ObjectNative::Equals`, which we find [in objectnative.cpp](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a077f271c3b5a8487f94111dc00a404a01fdc86b/src/coreclr/classlibnative/bcltype/objectnative.cpp#L139):

```cpp
FCIMPL2(FC_BOOL_RET, ObjectNative::Equals, Object *pThisRef, Object *pCompareRef)
{
    CONTRACTL
    {
        FCALL_CHECK;
        INJECT_FAULT(FCThrow(kOutOfMemoryException););
    }
    CONTRACTL_END;

    if (pThisRef == pCompareRef)
        FC_RETURN_BOOL(TRUE);

    // Since we are in FCALL, we must handle NULL specially.
    if (pThisRef == NULL || pCompareRef == NULL)
        FC_RETURN_BOOL(FALSE);

    MethodTable *pThisMT = pThisRef->GetMethodTable();

    // If it's not a value class, don't compare by value
    if (!pThisMT->IsValueType())
        FC_RETURN_BOOL(FALSE);

    // Make sure they are the same type.
    if (pThisMT != pCompareRef->GetMethodTable())
        FC_RETURN_BOOL(FALSE);

    // Compare the contents (size - vtable - sync block index).
    DWORD dwBaseSize = pThisMT->GetBaseSize();
    if(pThisMT == g_pStringClass)
        dwBaseSize -= sizeof(WCHAR);
    BOOL ret = memcmp(
        (void *) (pThisRef+1),
        (void *) (pCompareRef+1),
        dwBaseSize - sizeof(Object) - sizeof(int)) == 0;

    FC_GC_POLL_RET();

    FC_RETURN_BOOL(ret);
}
FCIMPLEND
```